# Parsing html forms input tag with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Well, I need to parse html forms, from the "input" , i need to extract the ones with the type "text" and anyone that is not text.

I have this code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as beatsop

html_data = open("forms.html")

def html_parser(html_data)
    html_proc = beatsop(html_data)
    #We extract the text inputs.
    txtinput = html_proc.findAll('input', {'type':'text'})
    #We extract the any kind of input that is not text.
    listform = ["radio", "checkbox", "password", "file", "image", "hidden"]
    otrimput = html_proc.findAll('input', {'type':listform})

html_parser(html_data)
```

I use it with local documents, but you can use urllib to request any web page with forms.
Now, the problem, I need to extract the "value" tag of the non-text input forms, and the "name" tag of the text ones.
Does anyone knows how can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access attribute of element, use `element['attribute']`.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as beatsop


def html_parser(html_data):
    html_proc = beatsop(html_data)
    #We extract the text inputs.
    txtinput = html_proc.findAll('input', {'type':'text'})
    listform = ["radio", "checkbox", "password", "file", "image", "hidden"]
    otrimput = html_proc.findAll('input', {'type': listform})

    print('Text input names:')
    for elem in txtinput:
        print(elem['name'])

    print('Non-text input values:')
    for elem in otrimput:
        value = elem.get('value')
        if value:
            print(value)
        else
            print('{} has no value'.format(elem))

with open("forms.html") as html_data:
    html_parser(html_data)
```

Comment: Are you a god? this worked like a charm. But I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "beatusup.py", line 21, in <module> html_parser(html_data) File "beatusup.py", line 18, in html_parser print(elem['value']) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 613, in getitem return self._getAttrMap()[key] KeyError: 'value'